# Set the color of a value in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, lwc-wire-adapter

I have fetched the data from apex method using wire adapter to lwc.

**js file**

```
if(data)
{
this.item=data.item;
this.itemColor=data.itemColor;
}
```

i have to set the color to the item value.i have tried this.

****html****

```
<div class="primary-num-text-medium" style="color:itemColor">{item}</div>
```

it is not working.can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few choices. Option 1 is to set the entire style:

```
<div style={style}>{item}</div>
```

Which is set in JavaScript:

```
this.style = `color: ${data.itemColor}`;
```

---

Option 2 is to set a CSS variable:

```
// css
div.itemColor {
  color: var(--itemColor);
}
```

Or:

```
<div style="color: var(--itemColor)">{item}</div>
```

And assign this class to the element:

```
<!-- markup -->
<div class="itemColor">{item}</div>
```

---

Which you then set in JavaScript on the element (if you used a class):

```
this.template.querySelector('div.itemColor').style.setProperty('--itemColor', data.itemColor);
```

Or to the entire component:

```
this.template.host.style.setProperty('--itemColor', data.itemColor);
```

In summary, there are lots of ways that you can achieve your effect. The one thing you can't do is the expression syntax from Aura.

Comment: @TeancyJohn Yes, you can have as many properties as you'd like.